# opening webpages within shiny window without opening a separate window

Tags: r, shiny

I have an URL which changes with an input on shiny app. I want to open an webpage and display that with in the tab panel of shiny window. Every time I change an input the webpage URL gets updated and I want to show that page in the same tab. As of now the web page opens in a separate window than the shiny window using browseURL function of R.

here is small test example for my case

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("opening web pages"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId='test',label=1,choices=1:5)
    ),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return((browseURL('http://www.google.com')))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({
    x <- input$test  
    getPage()
    })
})
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: i have included a code snippet of the same.

Answer (score 11):

Dont use `browseURL`. This explicitly opens the webpage in a new window.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui= fluidPage(
  titlePanel("opening web pages"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId='test',label=1,choices=1:5)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return((HTML(readLines('http://www.google.com'))))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({
    x <- input$test  
    getPage()
  })
})
)
```

If you want to mirror the page you can use an `iframe`

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui= fluidPage(
  titlePanel("opening web pages"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId='test',label=1,choices=1:5)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(tags$iframe(src = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
                       , style="width:100%;",  frameborder="0"
                       ,id="iframe"
                       , height = "500px"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({
    x <- input$test  
    getPage()
  })
})
)
```

Comment: but it's displaying it as plain html. most of the functions are giving "not found" error(like searching). is there any way we can open them as http connections?

Comment: You can use an `iframe` to mirror the page. `www.google.com` and many other websites send an X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header which blocks this however.